# class method can't be called cause it need a parameter

Tags: class, swift

This is only an example of what i am trying to do:

```
class Test{
    class func b(){
        a()
    }

    func a(){
        println("A")
    }
}
```

And in a other swift file i do:

```
Test.b()
```

But i get an error when i call `a()` in my `Test` class it says: `missing argument in call`

If i write `a(` it suggest me to call the method like this:  `a(Test)`, `Test` for the name of the class. So i try giving it the parameter `self` but it doesn't works

Comment: Stop. Rewrite your code so that classes have capital letters (`Test`) and don't show it until you do. This is a very important convention.

Comment: There is no concept of "self" unless there's an instance. A class method (or "Type Method" in Swift, since structs & enums can have methods too) shouldn't invoke methods or variables that require an instance, which is what you're trying to do. You could also make `func a()` a class/type method if you're just experimenting w/structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @matt said, `b` is a type method (or class, or static, however you want to call it), and requires a type to be executed (which in your case is `Test`):

```
Test.b()
```

On the other hand, `a` is an instance method, and requires an instance to be invoked.

So the only way to call `a` is with an instance of `Test`:

```
var test = Test()
test.a()
```

If you want to call from `b`, you have to either create an instance of `Test` in `b`:

```
class func b() {
    var test = Test()
    test.a()
}
```

or pass an instance of `Test` to `b`:

```
class func b(test: Test) {
    test.a()
}
```

However I think there's a flaw in your design. `b` should not be a class method, unless you use it to create an instance of `Test` to return to the caller:

```
class func b() -> Test {
    var test = Test()
    test.a()
    return test
}
```

There might be other cases when this kind of interaction can be useful - maybe if you explain what you are trying to achieve, we can provide a better answer.

Side note: the reason why autocompletion proposes `Test` is that instance method are curried type methods, taking an instance at the first call:

```
var test = Test()

test.a()

// Is equivalent to:

Test.a(test)()
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `a` is an instance method. The function `b` is a class method. A class method cannot call an instance method, as there is *no instance* in the story.

Thus your code is meaningless; I can't even imagine what you think you're trying to do (and neither, apparently, can the Swift compiler).

Comment: Can you tell me what should i do? to call function a

Comment: Not particularly helpful to berate the guy - people aren't born understanding OOP. It's only "nonsensical" and unimaginable if you can't remember being at that stage yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an example from C will help?

A *class method* is equivalent to a *static function* from C. It is just a function. An *instance method* (non-class) is equivalent to a C function that takes an additional (hidden) parameter: the instance which is the context for your method call.

An equivalent from C might look like this:

```
static void B() {
    ...
}

void A(Test test) {
    ...
}
```

You can't call *a()* from *b()* unless you have a *Test* object instance to pass for the first parameter.

What I mean is, in Swift, when you have a Test instance and you "call *a()* on it":

```
let test = Test()
test.a(...)
```

You are actually doing something like this:

```
let test = Test()
A(test,...)
```